# jQuery add/remove multiple selectbox options to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multiple selectbox and I need to add or remove list of items to the textbox with a comma but for now I am able to complete only till onclick add or remove single item and I am not sure how to add or remove multiple select options with comma and removing comma when unselected.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**My HTML:**

```
<select name="ascuisines" id="ascuisines" multiple="" class="chosen-select-width" tabindex="-1" required="" aria-required="true">
 <option value="" disable=""></option>
 <option value="African">African</option>
 <option value="Pizza">Pizza</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="getcuisines" />
<input type="button" value="Add Cuisines" id="addcuisines" />
```

**My JS:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#ascuisines').on('change', function () {
        $('#getcuisines').val(this.value);
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

**My Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/s1wq62qs/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .val() which will return an array of elements in case of a multiple select box

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ascuisines').on('change', function () {
        $('#getcuisines').val($(this).val().join());
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9g6mmjfh/)